# Can I use my hub to expand my network?

Tags: ethernet

I have one line of Ethernet, with no DHCP on it ( I have to assign IP manually). Now I want to turn that one line into 10 lines. I am using a Hub to do so, but it's not working.

There doesn't seem to be any WAN port on the Hub. It's just some Ethernet ports. So where does the main cable (that i want to divide) go? into a random port? I did that and I can'tr get a connection from other ports.

Comment: random port.  You will have to assign different valid IP's for the network to each machine, you can't re-use the same.

Comment: I did that, but then I only had access to my internal network, could not go outside.

Comment: check that the default gateway is set correctly and that the IP's are configured for external access at the router level--those are the two places I can see for road blocks. It seems if you can see the internal network that you are on the correct subnet.

Comment: but here is the thing: I connect the cable directly to my computer, I get internet. I connect the same cable to my hub, then connect my computer to my hub, no internet (internal only). why is that.

Comment: To answer that question I would capture the output of (assuming windows here each OS has an equivalent tho) `ipconfig /ALL` with both of those network setups (with and without the hub) and compare them.  With a hub you shouldn't need to flush the routing tables, but it might be an interesting try. `ipconfig /flushdns`

Answer (score 0):

In general, hubs are few and far between to find nowadays. But assuming it is indeed a hub (and not a switch or router) then you can select any port you want to be your uplink (in your case, WAN) port.

I usually pick either the lowest or highest port (furthest left or right of the ports just to make it easy to find later on).

At the other end of that cable needs to be an intelligent device capable of parsing frames and passing traffic on appropriately. Typically this would be a router, but it could be a layer 3 switch or a firewall device.

That device should have an IP address that maps to the default gateway address of the hosts/servers connected to the other ports on the hub.

You'll want to assign addresses to all the hosts/servers such that they have the same IP Network, which requires setting their netmask values to the same (typically, 255.255.255.0 in your case). Then, they each need a unique IP address that falls within the same netblock (typically, 192.168.1.[10 - 250]). Lastly, configure your router/switch/firewall that is on your WAN port to be 192.168.1.1 with the same netmask of 255.255.255.0 and assign that IP address as the default gateway on all of your hosts/servers.

Note: If you have more than a couple devices (4 or 5) trying to use the network at once your performance will degrade significantly. A switch is much more advisable and they are pretty cheap (you can probably get a 10-port switch for $6 USD).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a hub you need to have either static ip addresses for those units or use a router with dhcp enabled. My guess is that this is a corporate setup. If that is the case that port may be blocked when all the units are connected due to the fact that ten devices are connecting where there should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

You need a router. You need some device to masquerade for the devices on your internal network, otherwise only one device can have Internet access.